# How to use different calculation in one column using DAX?

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax, calculation

I have a table like this:
[image]

I would like to calculate the result but some of ID column has different calculation formula.
For ID less or equal to 1733 using this formula: `Value/3*100` for ID greater than 1733 using this formula `Value*100`

I tried this way:

```
Result = 
IF('Data'[ID]<=1733,[Value]/23*100)
IF('Data'[ID]>1733,[Value]*100)
```

But it return an empty value. Anyone could help me please.
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using IF statement by following way by creating a calculated column called "Result"

```
Result = IF(Data[ID]<="1733",(Data[VALUE]/23)*100,Data[VALUE]*100)
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Thanks, but it return an error `DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Text with values of type Integer. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values.`

Comment: what is the datatype of your ID column?

Comment: the format is text

Comment: Ideally ID Should be in Integer datatype, I think you should change the ID column datatype to integer and then give it a try

Comment: but I have some text in the ID that;s why I use text, if I change to number, the ID with txt become error

Comment: Then you have to warp 1733 in double quotes. I have edited the DAX query, Pls try now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250598/discussion-between-balaji-and-cheries).

Answer (score 0):

If the [ID] is a text then you can convert it to a number with the VALUE(). When you are trying to convert number to text with quotes then you will get  a wrong result for some of values. For text comparison it works like this: "11111"<"2", for number 11111 > 2. For a calculated column it not necessary to write a full column name like `'Data'[ID]`, you can simply write `[ID]`, because of a row context. DAX will understand that the value and row you are working with is in a current table.

```
Result =
    SWITCH(
        TRUE()
        ,VALUE([ID])<=1733,[VALUE]/23*100
        ,[VALUE]*100
    )
```